# For the obtuse ∠ABC, right ∠ADE, and FG where F is on AB and G is on BC what is the length of DE, where E is the bisector of FG

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, angle

For the obtuse ∠ABC, right ∠ADE, and FG where F is on AB and G is on BC what is the length of DE, where E is the bisector of FG.

The title technically explains it, but I've drawn a diagram to make it easier to understand.
[Diagram of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KorZx.png) (sorry for the poor quality).
I need two pieces of information from the diagram (I'm using this for a coding project, but that is only relevant because it explains why I don't use any numbers after this. All the values are dynamic). I need to find the measure of $\overline{DE}$ and the measure of ∠EFD (and I know I can find one once I have the other). Here's the information I have to start:

- The slopes of $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{BC}$ in $\frac{rise}{run}$
- The measure of ∠ABC is > 90
- ∠ADE is a right angle
- The length of $\overline{FG}$
- E bisects $\overline{FG}$

Using math, I know how to get:

- The measure of ∠ABC
- The measure of $\overline{FE}$ and $\overline{EG}$

This is where I get stuck. I have a bunch of information, but I can't figure out how to put it together. Thanks in advance for the help!

Note: Since I posted this question, I noticed several things that cause it to not be a full solution to the problem I need it for. Thus, I have posted an updated version. If you want to help me, here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76498751/finding-footing-for-proceedural-animation

Comment: As a note, I can probably find the measure of $\overline{DB}$ ahead of time as well (remember, this is a coding project), but I would like to avoid that if at all possible, since I know it'll be a pain.

Comment: I suppose $E$ is the midpoint of $FB$, not $FG$.

Comment: The length of $DE$ depends on the position of $F$ on $AB$.

Comment: no, I said $\overline{FG}$, I'm just bad at drawing and I made the diagram in google slides

Comment: Even in that case the length of $DE$ is half the distance of $G$ from line $AB$, hence its length can veary.

Comment: There is no other way. We need to know the measure of either $DB$ or $FD$.

Comment: i mentioned in an above comment I could add $\overline{DB}$ to the known information if nessicary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: ObtuseTriangle]

It is necessary to consider two slightly different cases here. What you see below is the solution for the case depicted in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$, in which the point $D$ lies between the two points $F$ and $B$. We leave OP to work out a solution for the case shown in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 2}$, in which the point $B$ lies between the two points $F$ and $D$.

Please note that all known lengths and angles are shown in $\bf{\color{red}{red}}$. We have extended the segment $AB$ and dropped a perpendicular to from $G$ to meet it at $H$. Furthermore, for brevity, we let $\angle GBH = \theta$ and $\angle GFB=\beta$. We start by applying the midpoint theorem to the right-angled triangle $FHG$ to obtain,
$$DE=\dfrac{GH}{2}=\dfrac{BG\sin\left(\theta\right)}{2} \qquad\text{and}\tag{1}$$
$$FD=\dfrac{FH}{2}=DB+BG\cos\left(\theta\right).\quad \tag{2}$$

When we apply the low of cosiness to the obtuse triangle $FBG$, we have,
$$FG^2=FB^2+BG^2+2FB\times BG\cos\left(\theta\right). \tag{3}$$

Now, using (2), we can express $FB$ as shown below.
$$FB=FD+DB=2DB+ BG\cos\left(\theta\right) \tag{4}$$

After replacing $FB$ in (3) using (4), we simplify (3) to obtain the following quadratic equation in $BG$.
$$\left(1+3\cos^2\left(\theta\right) \right)BG^2+\left(8DB\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)BG + 4DB^2-FG^2=0 \tag{5}$$

This equation has two real roots, but only one of them is positive, i.e.,
$$BG=\dfrac{\sqrt{\left(1+3\cos^2\left(\theta\right) \right)FG^2-4DB\sin^2\left(\theta\right)}-4DB\cos\left(\theta\right) }{1+3\cos^2\left(\theta\right) }. \tag{6}$$

We can use (1) and (6) to obtain the sought expression for the determination of length of $DE$.
$$DE=\dfrac{\sqrt{\left(1+3\cos^2\left(\theta\right) \right)FG^2-4DB\sin^2\left(\theta\right)}-4DB\cos\left(\theta\right) }{2\left(1+3\cos^2\left(\theta\right)\right)} \sin\left(\theta\right) $$

Finally, by considering the right angle triangle $FDE$, we can derive a formula to find the value of $\beta$.
$$\beta {\small{=\dfrac{DE}{FE}=\dfrac{2DE}{FG}=}} \sin^{-1} \left(=\dfrac{\sqrt{\left(1+3\cos^2\left(\theta\right) \right)FG^2-4DB\sin^2\left(\theta\right)}-4DB\cos\left(\theta\right) }{\left(1+3\cos^2\left(\theta\right)\right)FG }\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll have to spend a couple minutes rereading this before I fully understand it, but it looks correct!

Comment: There was an error in the equation (5).  Its second term was missing $BG$. I rectified it just now. I am sorry if  that error has caused any confusion.

Comment: No problem, I haven't implemented any of it yet, still working on actually adding $\overline{DB}$ to the known information.

Comment: A case I didn't realize was possible until recently, is one where $\overline{ED}$ is not paralel to $\overline{AB}$. If you want to take the time to solve that as well, I would be very greatful, but I believe you've given me enough of a push to solve that myself if you dont feel like it. And if it's not possible, please tell me xD

Comment: Do you mean the case, where $ED$ is not $\bf{perpendicular}$ to $AB$? If that the case, then I would like to recommend you to post it as a separate question from this one., so that others can also chip in. I will see what I can do.

Comment: Yep, sorry. Slip of the fingers. I'll try posting it as a seperate question.

Comment: Although, I'm probably gonna ask it on stack overflow, because a realization has come to me that has made fact that it is a coding project, (and the context of where I am using it in said coding project) much more relevant. I'll add a comment and edit the original question to include a link to that question.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-It is not determined because you can choose $\overline{FG}$ as you want (under your restrictions, of course).

[image]

Comment: I said I know the length of $\overline{FG}$. The length of $\overline{FG}$ is fixed.